# My code shows error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total += item
    return total
for key in prices:
    print compute_bill(key)
```

Comment: __Please format your code properly!__ Visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for help.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted this:

```
total += prices[item]
```

item is "banana" etc.. it's string, so you get this error

Comment: Then `compute_bill` will still iterate over the name of a food and try to add `prices["b"]`, `prices["a"]`, ...

Comment: I know, but he asked about error and said nothing about what the result should be

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `compute_bill` is `key`, e.g. `"banana"` ...

So the for-loop iterates over the characters in `key`. What you really want is in your homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in prices:
```

is retrieving "banana", "apple", etc. This is causing your compute_bill(food) method to try to add "banana" to your total. Total is an int and "banana" is a str, which is why you are receiving the error you are seeing.

Figure out how to use "banana" to get the actual price of the banana from the prices list and you should be good to go.